# Redirect function in Nuxt middleware is making state null

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication, jwt, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app in which everything works fine in middleware except when I use redirect.
When I comment the redirect('/admin') line it works fine even the state data is present when console logged. As soon as I uncomment the redirect line it makes the state null.
Please help if someone knows this issue. This exact code works in my other projects but not here.

This is my `auth.js` file in the middleware folder.

```js
export default function ({ store, route, redirect }) {
  const user = store.getters['user/user']
  const blockRouteAdmin = /\/admin\/*/g
  const blockRouteManager = /\/manager\/*/g
  const path = ['/signup', '/login']
  let value = path.includes(route.path)
  if (user) {
    if (user.isAdmin) {    
      if (!route.path.match(blockRouteAdmin)) {
        redirect('/admin')
      }
    }
    if (user.isManager) {
      if (!route.path.match(blockRouteManager)) {
          redirect('/manager')
      }
    }
    if (user.isUser) {
           if (
        route.path.match(blockRouteAdmin) ||
        route.path.match(blockRouteManager) ||
        value
      ) {
        console.log('isUser', user.isUser)
        redirect('/')
      }
    }
  }
  if (!user) {
    if (
      route.path.match(blockRouteAdmin) ||
      route.path.match(blockRouteManager)
    ) {
      redirect('/')
    } else {
      redirect()
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'aitl',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: ['~/plugins/firebaseConfig.js'],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/buefy
    'nuxt-buefy',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/content
    '@nuxt/content',
  ],

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
  },

  // Content module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-content
  content: {},

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},
}
```

My `index.js` inside store.

```js
import { vuexfireMutations } from 'vuexfire'
import { getUserFromCookie } from '../helper/index.js'

export const mutations = {
  ...vuexfireMutations,
}

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch, commit }, { req }) {
    try {
      const user = getUserFromCookie(req)
      if (user) {
        await dispatch('user/setUSER', {
          email: user.email,
          isAdmin: user.admin,
          isManager: user.manager,
          isUser: user.user,
          uid: user.user_id,
          name: user.name,
        })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },
}
```

`User.js` in store folder

```js
import { auth } from '../plugins/firebaseConfig'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export const state = () => ({
  user: null,
})

export const getters = {
  user(state) {
    return state.user
  },
}

export const actions = {
  async userlogin({ dispatch }, user) {
    try {
      const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      const userInfo = {
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.admin,
        isManager: user.manager,
        isUser: user.user,
        uid: user.uid,
        name: user.displayName,
      }
      Cookies.set('access_token', token)
      await dispatch('setUSER', userInfo)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },

  setUSER({ commit }, user) {
    commit('setUSER', user)
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  setUSER(state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },
}
```

Comment: `redirect` is only available on the server. Are you sure you are using this line only on the server?

Comment: Yes, it is present in middleware only. And this exact code works for me in other project.

Comment: It working in another project will not exactly help us here IMO. Maybe try to take the exact same files and check the difference. It is either a typo or some difference in the context your code is used in. I've formatted your code, looks a bit better now.

Comment: I understood the problem. Previously I was using target:'static' and later I switched to targer:'server'. And now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was solved by going from `target: 'static'` to `target: 'server'`, aka mirroring the settings of another working project.