# Is there a way to get blogs saved in hosted Strapi Admin panel to localhost:1337 or vice-versa?

Tags: heroku, nuxt.js, content-management-system, strapi, nuxt-strapi

My strapi cms is deployed to heroku. And I noticed if I create a blog on actual hosted admin panel it does not show up in localhost:1337 or when I publish a blog on localhost and again push it to heroku its still missing from there.
Like both are not in sync. Is there a way to sync blogs between hosted and localhost version?

Comment: Why don't you directly connect to production blog posts? If your thing is working, you basically don't need a local database anymore no? Otherwise, you'll need to have to call the API to extract your entries and inject them locally yeah.

Comment: Maybe try this package https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/744#issuecomment-789144481

Comment: My Strapi setup is complete and now I know its better to use just the hosted version instead of localhost. Localhost can be used for adding collections and make other changes.

Comment: @kissu. Can you please help me with this also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902289/redirect-function-in-nuxt-middleware-is-making-state-null